# Multiline Labels inside scrollView is shown only in a single line and expand to its full width

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uilabel, multiline

I have **UILabels** inside **UIScrollView**. *My labels can expand to more than one line*. i have set `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0` because it can expand to 2 or 3 lines. **It work fine when it is not shown inside UIScrollView**. but when i put it inside UIScrollView, this label is shown as one lengthy label and not breaking to multiple lines. instead horizontal scroll is shown. I don't want to show horizontel scroll, instead i want my lables to expand to more than two lines and cover only the width that is available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Content size of scrollview and set the frame of label... It will definitely work..

Answer (score 0):

you have to set new size of the label according to line increase or decrease like this.

```
-(NSInteger) linesCount {
    CGSize newSize = [self.lblstring sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.lblstring.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
    return newSize.height/self.lblstring.font.lineHeight;
}
```

so that you get that how many lines of label you have to do....